# Xubuntu visudo sudoers edit not working

Tags: xubuntu, sudo, visudo

I have been trying to specify a script that I would like to run without being prompted for a password. After a number of google and stack searches and a number of different syntax changes, I still cannot get it to work. One peculiar thing is that when typing `sudo visudo` nano is opened to edit the file. I never specified nano as the editor, but I may have first edited the file with nano. Would that make nano the default editor? If so, could that cause problems. Thanks for the help.

Here is my sudoers file.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) ALL
pat     ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/pat/test.sh

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: So, why exactly do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: When running `./test.sh` while in my home directory, I am prompted for a password.

Comment: How about `sudo ./test.sh`?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but the purpose is to have a script with `su pat -c "...`. The problem is that script cant run with this code unless a user is there to input a password.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

Realize that su, unless run from as root, requires you to provide the password of the user to su to.  The reason sudo ./test.sh works is, you are running test.sh as root! (sudo defaults to root if you don't give it a -u  switch.

So if you want the script to be able to su to another user it must be run as root (don't do this).

Why not just use "sudo -u pat" within the script, instead of "su pat -c"?

Answer (score 0):

The default editor of visudo is nano, no problem.

1) You will need to make some changes at your line

```
pat     ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/pat/test.sh
```

It should contain the name of the computer and a space before and after the "=":

```
username computername = NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

Something like this:

```
pat patcomputer = NOPASSWD: /home/pat/test.sh
```

2) The script should be owned by root. Run this at terminal:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/pat/test.sh
```

3) Set the right permissions:

```
sudo chmod 705 /home/pat/test.sh
```

4) Enjoy!